# OS X Sprite Kit - Dirty Rects/Regions

Tags: macos, core-animation, sprite-kit

**Some background:**

I have an existing OS X card game app that uses OpenGL.

The window is resizable, and a 4:3 aspect ratio is always maintained.

When the window is resized, the OpenGL view is resized accordingly. All visual elements are scaled accordingly. i.e. the cards maintain their relative sizes and distances from each other.

I'm interested in moving the code to a system that either uses Sprite Kit, or one predominantly based on Core Animation layers. Sprite Kit is more attractive to me in terms of feature set for my needs, but...

... I am concerned about Sprite Kit performance (or rather, needless performance, particularly on battery-powered Macs) for a game that essentially blasts the same textures to the screen, 60fps, even when nothing much is happening. (Most of the time, the cards are static, as the player ponders their next move.)

To reduce some of the (repetitive) drawing required, particularly at very large window sizes (e.g. fullscreen on a 30" monitor), I'm interested in using a "dirty rects/region" or "as-required" drawing system.

**Question:**

Does Sprite Kit provide some kind of dirty-rect drawing system, or the ability to implement such a drawing system?  (Or, is it basically going to draw everything over and over at 60fps, regardless of the need to redraw?)

Comment: CoreAnimation does not draw at 60fps when no animation is happening.

Comment: @mahal, indeed.  Which is why I'm considering shifting to Core Animation.  But I'd prefer Sprite Kit's feature set.

Answer (score 0):

SK is a OpenGL renderer, naturally it will redraw its contents every frame. That however doesn't make it slow. While the dirty rect drawing of UI frameworks is a way to improve performance but also to reduce power consumption, they have to use this approach because rendering in UI frameworks is typically a lot slower (often *not* hardware accelerated) than in an OpenGL renderer.

On the other hand SK can be slower frame over frame if the rendered scene's complexity is extreme. But that sounds highly unlikely for a card game.

Generally You shouldn't concern yourself with performance until you wrote some code to test it with. Premature optimization and all...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It's not so much about premature optimisation, rather, picking the right drawing strategy in the first place.  At the moment, my game is firing away 60fps, but it really doesn't need to be.  Ideally, I'd like the features of Sprite Kit, but without necessarily having to update at 60fps ... only when something has actually been drawn.  It's more about battery life/cpu usage for users than anything, especially mobile ones. Cheers.

Comment: in that case use a UI framework and stay away from sprite kit, cocos2d, or other opengl based render engines - they are optimized more for best performance rather than battery life

Comment: (I'm not being argumentative here, just pointing that all rendering on  iOS/OS X is fundamentally OpenGL based.)

Anyway, I think I'll have to go with a CA based approach for flexibility. Cheers.

Comment: yup, that's true, the difference is mainly whether screen contents get cleared every frame or not. UI frameworks keep the renderbuffer and keep drawing to it, only clearing parts of it when the app tells the framework to invalidate a specific region. Theoretically game engines could be designed the same way but never are because there's the assumption that for almost all games the screen contents change fundamentally frame by frame.